# Python 3.5.1: How Do I Make The while-loop Run in class?

Tags: python, class, while-loop, user-input, python-3.5

I was researching how classes work and I figured out how to make a class work in **some** scenarios. But I couldn't find a way in which to make my scenario work. It involves `class Function():`, `def __init__(self):`, and `def AnotherFunction(self, Foo):`. Those aren't the actual "Functions" in my scenario but, they are very similar. Here is my code:

```
class Name():
    def __init__(self, Name):
        self.Name = ["Your Dicer's name is: "]
        self.AddName()
    def AddName(self):
        self.Count = 1
        while(self.Input == 1):
            Input = input("What is your Dicer's name?:\n")
            if(any(BadWord in Input.lower() for BadWord in [])):
                print("That's an inappropriate name! Try again")
            elif(len(Input) < 3):
                print("That name is too short! Try again.")
            elif(len(Input) > 16):
                print("That name is too long! Try again.")
            else:
                self.Count -= 1
        self.Name.append(Input)
```

My question is, why wont the `while loop` occur in `class`? I tried looking up other stack overflow questions, class article and tutorials, and other questions related to while loops but to no avail. Can you tell me why it wont run and how to fix this? I would appreciate that. Thanks! :)

**Update 1: I put `Input` in the `AddName parameters`. I also added `Name` as an `instance`. But these updates didn't work.**

**Update 2: I took `Input` out of the `AddName parameters`. I also changed `self.Input` to `self.Count` so it doesn't get confusing. I also changed `self.Name += Input` to `self.Name.append(Input)`. These updates made the code somewhat easier to understand and fixed some of the problems but, the `while loop` wont run.**

Comment: You call your function without the required arguments (`self.AddName()`), either supply an argument for the parameter `Input` or change the function definition to `def AddName(self): ...`.

Comment: if you create an instance of `Name` by calling the constructor `x = Name()` it would raise a TypeError because `AddName` takes an argument that you do not give it so I'm assuming the issue is that you are never creating an instance.

Comment: @Jim Both of those suggestions don't work

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald I put an argument `Input` in for `AddName` but nothing happened.

Comment: let me bold the important parts of my above comment:  "if you **create an instance of Name by calling the constructor `x = Name()`** it would raise a TypeError because AddName takes an argument that you do not give it so **I'm assuming the issue is that you are never creating an instance.** " The functions you have written do not execute unless you call them, in this case `__init__` is called when you instantiate your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is on these lines:

```
    self.AddName()
def AddName(self, Input):
```

The second one shows that the `AddName` expects one argument in addition to `self`. The previous line however, is a call that doesn't pass any argument. You need to make those two match up properly.

I think in this case, you don't need an `Input` parameter for `AddName`. The `Input` variable you're using in the function comes from user input (the `input` function), and the argument is completely ignored. (Note, there's also a `self.Input` attribute, which is unrelated other than having a very confusingly similar name).

Here's a minimally fixed version:

```
class Name():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = ["Your Dicer's name is: "]
        self.AddName()
    def AddName(self):              # no Input paramter needed on this line!!!!
        self.Input = 1
        while(self.Input == 1):
            Input = input("What is your Dicer's name?:\n")
            if(any(BadWord in Input.lower() for BadWord in [])):
                print("That's an inappropriate name! Try again")
            elif(len(Input) < 3):
                print("That name is too short! Try again.")
            elif(len(Input) > 16):
                print("That name is too long! Try again.")
            else:
                self.Input -= 1
        self.Name += Input           # you may want self.Name.append(Input) here
```

This "works" in the sense that it doesn't raise an exceptions, but it probably doesn't quite do what you want. The last line, `self.Name += Input` appends each character of the inputted name onto the list `self.Name`. That's not very useful. Probably you want `self.Name.append(Input)` or maybe `self.Name` shouldn't be initialized to be a list in `__init__`.

There are also a vast number of style issues with this code. I'd strongly recommend renaming *all* of the variables and attributes. Normal Python style is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for functions, methods, attributes and most variables. Only classes have `CapitalizedNames`. The `self.Input` attribute you're using is also confusingly similar to the local variable `Input` while they don't really mean anything very close to one another (there's also no need for `self.Input` to be an instance attribute, rather than a local variable of some kind).

Here's a rewrite of your code that doesn't do much different, but has much better style:

```
class Name():
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            name = input("What is your Dicer's name?:\n")
            if(any(bad_word in name.lower() for bad_word in [])):
                print("That's an inappropriate name! Try again")
            elif(len(name) < 3):
                print("That name is too short! Try again.")
            elif(len(name) > 16):
                print("That name is too long! Try again.")
            else:
                self.name = name
                break

    def __str__(self):
        return "Your Dicer's name is: {}".format(self.name)
```

If you're going to call the `AddName` method just once from `__init__`, there may not be much point in having it be a separate function. Here I've just merged it right in to `__init__`. I've also done away with `self.Input`, in favor of a `while True` loop, and use `break` to exit it when we get a valid name. The potentially invalid name is being stored in a variable named `name` rather than `Input`, and I've moved the `"Your Dicer's name is"` text to the `__str__` method, rather than having it be part of the `name` attribute.

But I'm not really sure why you're using a class here in the first place. Usually a class represents a concrete "thing" that exists in your program. A `Name` is a very abstract sort of "thing". While it's not always unreasonable to have a `Name` class, more often, a `name` would simply be an attribute attached to some other object (like a `Dicer`, perhaps, whatever that is).

Comment: The `While loop` still isn't being executed in those answers. And the reason I'm using a `class` "function" (or whatever you call class), is because this is just one of the things I'm using `class` for. I'm also using it for `roles` and `levels`. Do you think I should add the all into the `class` function to give it more uuph?

Comment: How are you trying to use the code? How can you tell if the `while` loop runs or not? It works for me when, at the top level (e.g. not in the class) I do `n = Name()`. I have no idea what your other question means. Please read a Python tutorial so you get the terminology down and can communicate better.